# duas funções dentro do onchange

Tags: javascript

Colegas.

Estou tentando colocar duas funções dentro do onchange, porém as funções só funcionam quando tiro uma ou outra.

```
onchange="soma(); alterar();"
```

Como eu poderia resolver isso?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A melhor maneira seria usar `.addEventListener` assim

```
el.addEventListener('change', soma);
el.addEventListener('change', alterar);
```

Outra opção seria passar uma função que chame as duas:

```
onchange="processar();"
```

e

```
function processar(){
    soma();
    alterar();
}
```

Caso essas duas funções tenham lógica comum era melhor ter uma a chamar a outra.

Outra opção ainda é colocar todas as ações separadas por vírgulas para o JavaScript executar todas:

```
onchange="(soma(), alterar());"
```

Exemplo:

```html
Clica aqui:
<input type="checkbox" onChange="(alert(1), alert(2));">
```

Comment: Obrigado Sérgio.

Comment: Em versões antigas do IE o `addEventListener` não funciona, tem que usar o `attachEvent`. O `attachEvent` espera os eventos com o prefixo `on`. Sugestão: `if (el.attachEvent) { el.attachEvent("onchange", foo, true); } else { el.addEventListener("change", foo); }`