# 2 requisições no onClick

Tags: javascript

tenho um onClick em uma imagem com 2 requisições:

1) um verifica
2) um redirect

```
function verifica(Msg) {
 return confirm(Msg);
}
```

E a imagem:

```
 <img 
     src="'.$imagemExclui.'"
     align="center" 
     style="height: 40px;" 
     title="Excluir Produto"
     onClick="return verifica(\''.$mensagem.'\');
                     document.location=\'?acao=remove&indice='.$produto["idProdutos"].'\'"; />
```

Mas quando eu chamo a função verifica, se eu retiro o `return` ela funciona, mas mesmo que seleciono sim, ela não segue, se eu deixo e `return`, ela não funciona.

O que fazer?

Comment: Possivel duplicada de http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88536/129

Comment: Para este caso em específico também é possível fazer: `onclick="if(verifica(...)){ document.location=... }` ao invés do `return`.

Comment: Perfeito Anderson, era isso que eu precisava. Obrigado!